# Probability of drawing certain cards

Tags: probability

I have to calculate the chance that, drawing 5 cards from a deck of 52 playing cards, the first one is a queen and the fifth one is a king. My thinking was that the number of wanted outcomes in this case would be $$4*4*50!\over47!*3!$$. My reasoning behind this was that you have 4 chances for both the first and last position, and 3 remaining positions for the remaining 50 cards. With a total number of $$52!\over47!*5!$$ possibilities to draw the 5 cards, my result was:

$${{4*4*50!\over52!*3!}\over{52!\over47!*5!}} = {80\over663}$$

However, according to the guide, the actual answer is:

$${4*4*(50*49*48)}\over{52!\over47!}$$

And I can not figure out why. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Those 3 choices can be permuted in $3!$ ways, and the number of ways to choose those 5 cards is $5!*\binom{52}{5}$

Comment: For the denominator we want $(52)(51)(49)(48)(47)$. The numerator should be $(4)(4)(50)(49)(48)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, where did the $50$ go?

Comment: For the record to avoid potential confusion, Andre does in fact have a typo.  He meant to put $52\cdot 51\cdot \underline{50}\cdot 49\cdot 48$ for the denominator.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is the product $52$ down to $48$.  I am doing it sort of in your style, counting at the bottom all **ordered** ways of getting $5$ cards. But there is a better way. The probability the first is a Queen is $4/52$, and given that, the probability that the fifth is a King is $4/51$. We need not worry about the other cards at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q_1$ represent the event that the first card drawn is a queen and $K_5$ represent the event that the fifth card drawn is a king.

The problem asks you to find $Pr(Q_1\cap K_5)$.

> The multiplication principle: $$Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B|A)$$

So, $Pr(Q_1\cap K_5)= Pr(Q_1)\cdot Pr(K_5|Q_1)$

$Pr(Q_1)$ is the probability that you draw a queen for the first card.  There are 4 queens out of 52 cards total, for a probability of $\frac{4}{52}=\frac{1}{13}$.

$Pr(K_5|Q_1)$ is the probability of drawing a king for the fifth card given that the first card was a queen.  You may make the simplification in your mind that $Pr(K_5|Q_1)=Pr(K_2|Q_1)$, I.e. that we can draw the "fifth" card early.  As such, there are 4 kings available out of 51 cards remaining (since there is one queen missing from the deck already) for a probability of $\frac{4}{51}$.

As such, $Pr(Q_1\cap K_5) = Pr(Q_1)\cdot Pr(K_5|Q_1) = \frac{1}{13}\cdot \frac{4}{51}$

---

Indeed, $\frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}{\frac{52!}{47!}} = \frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48\cdot 47!}{52!} = \frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 50!}{52!} = \frac{4\cdot 4}{52\cdot 51} = \frac{1}{13}\cdot\frac{4}{51}$

---

As per request, here is an approach which avoids the use of the probability version of the multiplication principle and instead focuses on the counting version of the multiplication principle.

Here, we will let our sample space, $S$, be all 5 card hands (where order matters) of a standard 52-card playingcard deck.  By multiplication principle, there are $52\cdot 51\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48 = \frac{52!}{47!}$ number of different outcomes.

Noting that every outcome is equally likely, we can use the formula for probability in an equiprobable sample space, $Pr(E) := \frac{|E|}{|S|}$.

So, we wish to count how many different outcomes satisfy the requirement that the first card is a queen and the fifth card is a king.  Set up a multiplication principle argument in the following way:

- Pick which queen it is in the first slot (four choices)
- Pick which king it is in the fifth slot (four choices)
- Pick which of the remaining cards is in the second slot (50 choices)
- Pick which of the remaining cards is in the third slot (49 choices)
- Pick which of the remaining cards is in the fourth slot (48 choices)

By multiplication principle, there are $4\cdot 4\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48$ different such hands.

Thus, the probability is $\frac{4\cdot 4\cdot 50\cdot 49\cdot 48}{\frac{52!}{47!}}$ which by earlier calculation simplifies to $\frac{1}{13}\cdot \frac{4}{51}$.

Notice, here we again used the simplification that we may choose the outcome of the spots with the most restriction first.  Indeed, we needed to if we were to use the multiplication principle.  Otherwise, we would have needed to do a very tedious case-by-case analysis attempting to answer the question of which king it is for the final space depending on how many kings were already chosen.

The tedious version: break it into cases.  Let $n$ represent "not a king", of which after the first queen was drawn, there will be 47 left.

$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
first & second & third & fourth & fifth & total\\
Q & n & n & n & K & 4\cdot 47\cdot 46\cdot 45\cdot 4\\
Q & K & n & n & K & 4\cdot 4\cdot 47\cdot 46\cdot 3\\
Q & n & K & n & K & 4\cdot 47\cdot 4\cdot 46\cdot 3\\
Q & n & n & K & K & 4\cdot 47\cdot 46\cdot 4\cdot 3\\
Q & K & K & n & K & 4\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 47\cdot 2\\
Q & K & n & K & K & 4\cdot 4\cdot 47\cdot 3\cdot 2\\
Q & n & K & K & K & 4\cdot 47\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\\
Q & K & K & K & K & 4\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1
\end{array}$

Indeed, by summing over all cases, you will arrive at the same amount

Comment: Why can we make the simplification that we draw the fifth card second? Wouldn't drawing 3 other cards change the chance for the fifth one to be a king, e.g. because one of those 3 is a king as well?

Comment: Also, do you have an idea of how they reached the format for the given answer (in my original question)? I'm pretty sure that it's supposed to partially show how they came to their answer, and the format I used in my question to answer it is a method of counting we have to practice now.

Comment: The short answer is that there is a bijection between the situation of drawing the cards in the order of "first, second, third, fourth, fifth" and the situation of drawing the cards in the order of "first, fifth, second, third, fourth."  The longer answer is that through tedious arithmetic and case-analysis, the numbers will be equivalent.  And sure, I'll write up an additional solution that involves counting principles instead of probability principles.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been a great help!

Comment: @ErikDolor added information on the tedious method of calculation (which although is interesting to see once, I recommend never using unless absolutely necessary).

Comment: Thanks again! The second method you used was clearly the method employed by the guide, and is quite obvious in hindsight. Altogether, this is a great answer, and it makes the relation between various ways of finding a probability clearer for me. If I could upvote you more, I would.